# Intermittent boot anomaly: has anybody heard of a system's screen going back to the startup image, a minute or so after the Gnome desktop comes up?

Tags: gnome, startup, pop-os

This is a weird one.

I have a new System76 Meerkat, running POP, and (intermittently, seemingly at random, maybe once out of 10 system startups), a minute or so after the Gnome desktop appears, the screen reverts to the System76 startup screen, at which point, the only thing it appears to respond to is the power button (which appears to simply initiate a normal power-down).

It either happens within the first few minutes after the Gnome desktop appears, or it doesn't happen at all. It has happened while the system was completely idle, and it has happened while I was navigating the settings screen. And it has **never** happened twice in a row.

For all I know, the Gnome desktop (and any open applications) might still be there, and might still be responsive to keyboard and mouse activity, but simply hidden behind that startup screen.

I already have a support ticket open on this.

Comment: Maybe me, too. I'm running headless, so I can't see what's going on, but recently my older Meerkat (2018) started exhibiting this behavior. It dies about a minute after booting, not always, and worse: sometimes the power button doesn't light up. If I unplug it, then plug it back in, the power button doesn't light up (red). If I wait a while (not sure how long yet), it eventually lights up red again and I can boot it.

Comment: I don't want to inundate System76 with support tickets, so please let me know if you get anywhere with them.